# JProfiler not able to detect WebSphere JVM

Tags: windows, jvm, websphere, jprofiler, local-system-account

I am facing an issue with JProfiler: the issue is it is not able to detect JVM of WebSphere which is running.

I see WebSphere is running as a Windows service as a local system account. So, I tried the "show Services" option, but, it still doesn't detect the JVM.

Its really taking lot of time for me to resolve this issue, can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on the auto-detection feature you can simply startup a JVM [with the agent pre-attached](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/sessions/remoteTable.html) so you simply have to connect the frontend to the agent's listening port.

Answer (score 0):

Attach mode in JProfiler does not support IBM JVMs, you have to profile like in the answer by @the8472.